# Amcharts heatmap chart translate country names

Tags: jquery, heatmap, amcharts

I have an Amcharts heatmap chart with a world map. I would like to translate country names in Italian in the balloon text.
I have a file where the names of the countries are translated in Italian, like this `var mapTranslations = {"Andorra": "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates": "Emirati Arabi Uniti", "Afghanistan": "Afghanistan", "Bosnia and Herzegovina": "Bosnia Erzegovina", "Barbados": "Barbados", "Bangladesh": "Bangladesh", "Belgium": "Belgio"` but I cannot call the translated name in the balloon text. 
If I use

```
"areasSettings": {
        "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]] sessioni"
    },
```

I see country names in English with the corresponding value, but if I try to call mapTranslations in the balloonText property I get Undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmMaps comes withs its own translations for many languages, including Italian. All you have to do is include the maps' `"it.js"` translation file and set the [`language`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#language) property to `"it"`, for example:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "language": "it",
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  }
});
```

```css
#mapdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/lang-maps/it.js"></script>

<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

Note that if you're including the language file directly from the amcharts website you have to use the lang-maps directory. If you're hosting the amcharts files on your webserver, the language files are in the lang directory.

If you need to use your own translation file, I recommend following the amcharts format in the language files and use the `language` property.