# Change / translate country names to different language for Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

This seems like a basic question, however, I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation or here on stackoverflow.

I'm trying to get the translated country names for my map that I generated with amcharts4.

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284354/amcharts-heatmap-chart-translate-country-names), however, this is specified for amcharts3. When I try to set the language property of a chart series like this in amcharts4,
`chart.language = 'nl';`,
 I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` which I believe is the standard error for when you set an unsupported property.

I also found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538057/amcharts-v4-ammap-change-language), which says you should set `chart.language.locale` , this works for amcharts4, **but does not translate the country names**. This only translates the used units and dates etc.

So my questions is, "How do I change the country names for a generated map in amcharts4?"

Answer (score 1):

So, the official answer from amcharts is this:

> No, I'm afraid. We currently do not have a ready-made solution for
>   country name translations :(

What I did was grab a translation json file from [this repository](https://github.com/stefangabos/world_countries/tree/master/data). 
I did a find and replace to remove the property and value of property `id`.
I changed the property name `alpha2` to `id`, and converted it's value to uppercase.

So for instance

```
{"id":4,"name":"Afghanistan","alpha2":"af","alpha3":"afg"}
```

Will become

```
{"name":"Afghanistan","id":"AF","alpha3":"afg"}
```

This will then essentialy become your translation object.

I then declared a variable `translations` and gave it this complete object as a value.

I then added this as data to my polygonSeries. `polygonSeries.data = translations;` .

Because this now overwrites the name property with the translated value, the hover effects should be with the translated value.